# Stub radio button in Konacha Javascript spec

Tags: javascript, konacha

Here is my Javascript:

```
if $("#payment_cc:checked").length > 0
  path = "/orders"
  if @get('tokenize')
    @_submitWithToken(obj, path)
  else
    @_submitWithCC(obj, path)
else
  path = "/orders/paypal"
  @_submitWithCC(obj, path)
```

I am trying to simulate in my Javascript spec so that I can test when:

```
$("#payment_cc:checked").length == 1
$("#payment_cc:checked").length == 0
```

How should I set the `length` of `$("#payment_cc:checked")` in my Konacha test?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the `length` of a jQuery element selection, just set the radio button to be checked manually like this:

```
describe('when the radio is selected', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        $('#payment_cc').attr('checked', true);
    });

    it('should do something', function() {
        // Assert that the submission went the way you wanted it to
    });
});
```

Comment: Should the `if...else` be changed?

Comment: Generally - no, you shouldn't change the code you are testing, it should work the way it would like if it was the real user that clicked the radio button.